# Book trilogy from the 1970's or 60's with snow wolves, some kind of water people, bird people, and one hero

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

It was a trilogy and the protagonist had to travel to either three different worlds or three different parts of the same world.

One part was a based on water, with people or people-like creatures who lived in the water. The second part was based on people who were like "birds" or at least had wings. The last book was based on a frozen terrain with snow wolves.

Comment: Sounds quite like William Tedford's Timequest trilogy from the early 1980s. In each book, the main character, Chayn Jahil, meets a different planet of adapted humans - one water for sure, one cold. His companion is a small, blue humanoid.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure it was before 1980 and it was the Timequest trilogy. But thanks again. I also think it was a Del-Rey print, but I could be wrong on that.

Comment: Gotcha. I have another thought. Was the main character traveling to the universe, these worlds to create a next-level messiah/savior figure? Were the flying men called Pteromen and the ocean ones called Androxi?

Comment: I don't think those character names were in the story. I'm really not sure what the protagonist was doing no the world. I think it was only one world and he got there by space craft if I remember correctly. It was a space port and then he went on these adventures, but they were on the same world